# how to launch firefox in private mode with the keyboard?

Tags: command-line, firefox, browser, privacy, gui

How to launch a new private firefox window from the "type here to search" box in the start menu?  (I think this is the same as `windows key`+`r` and then typing in "firefox" but not sure.  There seem some distinctions between powershell, dos prompt and the GUI.)

see also:

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/8y2skr/opening_a_private_window_with_a_specific_url_from/

Certainly, simply typing in "firefox" launches the browser.

Answer (score 3):

It should be easy enough to just start Firefox and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. The official documentation on [command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) highlights that running `firefox -private` should get you into private mode easily. Also there should be support for `-private-window` and `-private-window <URL>`.